# apache lucene tokens

Tags: apache, lucene, indexing

I started experimenting Apache Lucene Core 4 and my question is...
Lets asume that I created Index of some text and it is stored in a Field with name "context"
Is it posible to get the list of tokens of this field, that was successfully indexed?
I am looking at IndexReader and Field, but have no idea how to retrieve tokens.

Comment: AS I remember you can get the Document, with the stored text. But I have no idea if you can access to the analyzed tokens, I think no, because it depends of the Tokenizer you used. And in the majority of cases, all text you give, without stop words and so on, is the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- you can re-analyze a stored field,
- or use [term vectors](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) (provided you enabled term vectors at indexing time).

Comment: Is it posible to specify creation of term vectors, when using TextField when creating Index?

Comment: no, you need to create your own FieldType instance and then use it in the Field constructor

Comment: It is interesting that I have an iterator of terms for the document. Is it possible to find out the position number of each of the term?

Comment: You need to seek for your term, and then get its DocsAndPositionsEnum,  the nextPosition method will give you the position numbers.